# Varnish +nginx + ISPConfig

Tags: linux, nginx, varnish

Can't configure Varnish. Please, help!

(found here only german thread)
I've setted up  Nginx 1.10 , Varnish 4.1.1, ISPconfig.

/etc/default/**varnish**

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
-T localhost:6082 \
-f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
-S /etc/varnish/secret \
-s malloc,512m"
```

​
/etc/varnish/**default.vcl**

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "81";
}
acl purge {
"localhost";
"127.0.0.1";
}​
```

Nginx virtual host /etc/nginx/sites-available/**MyDomain.com.vhost**

```
server {
listen *:81;
...​
```

and when I visite MyDomain.com it shows me content from my server IP adress
/var/www/**html**/index.html instead /var/www/**MyDomain.com**/web/index.html

What's wrong?
I don't know what to look first, how to debug ?

Answer (score 0):

Your varnish listen on `:6081` and forward all requests to `127.0.0.1:81`.
Your nginx listen on `*:81`

You should request `MyDomain.com` on port 6081.

If you request `MyDomain.com` on port 80 you are redirected to the default nginx page.

If you want to make sure, I would suggest to run a `varnishlog` which will tell you what's passing through varnish in real time.